# Select control element in Visual Studio in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new in ASP.NET, and I have a website which I opened it by MS Visual 2010. The problem is when I try to select a control element I can not because it seems behind `ContentPlaceHolder`. See the image below, what can I do!

[image]

Here is the code of the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<title>Job Seekers : Search Job in Oman</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <asp:Table runat="server" Width="800" style="direction: ltr" Visible="False">
    <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Top">

        <asp:TableCell ID="cell_register" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2" VerticalAlign="Top" ColumnSpan="2" CssClass="tdcloud2">            
        <h2>Last News</h2>
        <div id="news" runat="server"></div>
 </asp:TableCell>
         <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="200" CssClass="tdcloud">
            <h2>Site Services</h2>

            <hr /><br />
            <img src="Images/bullet.png" />  <a href="AvailableJobs.aspx">Available Jobs</a><br />
            <img src="Images/bullet.png" />  <a href="CompaniesProfiles.aspx">Compnaies Profiles</a><br />
            <img src="Images/bullet.png" />  <a href="AddCompany.aspx">Register Company</a>
         </asp:TableCell>

    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Top">
            <asp:TableCell ID="cell_login" runat="server" Width="200" CssClass="tdcloud">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <hr />
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_error" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="error"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_email" runat="server" Text="Email:" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_email" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_password" runat="server" Text="Password:" CssClass="label" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_company" runat="server" /><asp:Label ID="lbl_company" runat="server" Text="Company" CssClass="" ></asp:Label>
            <br /><asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" Text="Login" 
        onclick="btn_login_Click" />
        <br /><br />
            <a href="Forget.aspx">Forget Password ?</a>
            <br />
            <a href="Register.aspx">Regsiter</a>
            <hr />
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell ID="cell_logged" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="tdcloud">
            <h2>Account</h2>
            <hr />
            <img src="Images/users.png" />
            <div><span class="bold"><%=Session["email"] %><%=Session["company"] %></span> </div>
            <br />
            <%
                if (Session["company"] != null)
                {
                    %>
                    <div><a href="CompInfo.aspx">Company Information</a></div>
                    <div><a href="SeekersApplications.aspx">Seekers Applications</a></div>
                    <div><a href="ChangePasswordCompany.aspx">Change Password</a></div>
                    <div><a href="AddJob.aspx">Add Job</a></div>

                        <%
                }
                else
                {
                    %>
                                <div><a href="PersInfo.aspx">Personal Information</a></div>
                    <div><a href="JobApplications.aspx">Job Applications</a></div>
                    <div><a href="ChangePasswordSeeker.aspx">Change Password</a></div>
                        <div><a href="UploadCv.aspx">Upload CV</a></div>
                    <%
                }
            %>

            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_SinOut" runat="server" Text="Sign Out" 
        onclick="btn_SinOut_Click" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Are you sure you want to sign out?" id="lbl_note" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_yes" runat="server" Text="yes" 
        onclick="yes" Visible="false" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_no" runat="server" Text="no" 
        onclick="no" Visible="false" />
        <hr />
        </asp:TableCell>    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Top">

        <asp:TableCell><h2>Advertisements</h2><a href="http://nawras.om"><img src="Images/nawras.jpg" width="80" height="80" /></a>  <a href="http://www.oxy.com"><img src="Images/oxy.jpg" width="80" height="80" /></a>  <a href="http://www.pdo.co.om/"><img src="Images/pdo.gif" width="80" height="80" /></a></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><center><h2>New Jobs</h2></center>
        <div id="jobs" runat="server"></div>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><center><h2>Jobs ends soon</h2></center><div id="jobsends" runat="server"></div></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><center><h2>Contact</h2></center><center><a href="Contact.aspx"><img title="Contact Me" width="150" src="Images/contact.jpg" /></a></center></asp:TableCell>

    </asp:TableRow>


    </asp:Table>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: go to the source of the designer, you can move around the button there

Comment: @JaneDoe: what about if i want to drag another element or change its position!

Comment: @you can do that by going to the source of your designer page. you can move around your controls there, or add new controls programatically. for instance: you can just write <asp:Button id="test" runat="server" text="Click me"/> and you'll see that it works. if you want it to change position, you'll be better off doing it manually aswell, try adding a few <br/> tags between the password textbox and the login button, you'll see that it'll move. It's not ideal, but thats the only thing i can think of atm

Comment: @JaneDoe So what is the benefit of the IDE if always need to write the code!! What made the page locked form drag any element!

Comment: i know, and what you want to do *is* possible, but i dont know what the problem is in this situation. try making a new fresh page, and try to drag controls there. if that works, compare the 2 pages and see where the difference is

Comment: also if the pages contains several elements how can I determine the event of each one! how can i know the name of the element!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14563/discussion-between-jane-doe-and-adban)

Comment: place the html markup where the control reside.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a control and could not choose that control from your designer control holder,in design mode, click F4 and on the top of Properties box, you can find a list of all controls in your form/page, as listed into a listbox. But if you want to select a part of control, ex: login button of a login control, over the mouse on the control, and click control task (a little **>** sign) and click **Convert to Template**,this action explodes the control and you can select each part of it, as you want.

Comment: Where I can find `control task`?

Comment: in design mode, select login control,on top-left of it, a rectangular that holds a small **>** sign will be appear, that's it.

Comment: I can not select the control, when I try to select it, the `ContentPlaceHolder1` is selected above the button as it appears in the picture, I can not touch the control.

Comment: you can access the control from masterpage.master, if you use a masterpage.

Comment: There is a masterpage, but there is no control on it except `ContentPlaceHolder1`

Comment: would you please add source code of the page that contains login control, in your main post?

Comment: try this:If you want to select a control and could not choose that control from your designer control holder,in design mode, click F4 and on the top of Properties box, you can find a list of all controls in your form/page, as listed into a listbox

Comment: I suggest use div's element to arrange and design your web forms, if not, use Html table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a `master page` and trying to access the master page's control from content page. If this is the case then, go to master page and access the control there. Otherwise look for the control in source view instead of design view.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple solution 
- > cut control from table cell and paste outside table.
- > perform your action what you want 
-> then again cut the control and paste again in the previous cell.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim btn as Button 
btn=Me.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("btn_login"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.